# Xamarin - NSURL returning null

Tags: ios, xamarin, nsurl

I am building an app using Xamarin's Unified API and am creating a NSUrl with a string. However the app crashes as soon as I try to create the NSUrl.

```
string url = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=" + destination; 
NSUrl googleMapsURL = new NSUrl (url);
```

The value of `url` is `comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=600+Drake+Apartments\n600+Drake+St,+Vancouver+BC+V6B+5W7,+Canada`

The message in the console is:

> Could not initialize an instance of the type 'Foundation.NSUrl': the
>   native 'initWithString:' method returned nil. It is possible to ignore
>   this condition by setting
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work (tested with your above code).

```
using System.Web.Services;
...

string destination = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
    "600 Drake Apartments\n600 Drake St, Vancouver BC V6B 5W7, Canada");
```

Now turns into

```
"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=600+Drake+Apartments%0a600+Drake+St%2c+Vancouver+BC+V6B+5W7%2c+Can…"
```

Add Reference System.Web.Services to the project. My guess is that your URL encoding, wherever it's coming from isn't compatible with what the Apple APIs expect.

Comment: I have seen URL encoding fail when you assume a perfectly valid looking character is going to be okay. Sometimes if data is copy + pasted, it might be a Unicode version of a comma, or a quotation mark, differences not always visible to the naked eye.